# How to add texture pack in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android

I have Minecraft 0.10.4 in an unrooted Android 4.0.4 and I would like to use a texture pack. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but very hard, there really is no "easy" guide. The link to some texture packs and how to download them are below

http://mcpeuniverse.com/texture-packs/